# Ajax, PHP Problemas na hora de receber dados

Tags: php, ajax, json

Bom pessoal, meu problema é o seguinte. Eu tenho uma função JS para fazer uma consulta no banco de dados mysql via ajax, ela retorna aparentemente corretamente mas quando vou tentar acessar o valor da "undefined"
Isto é um alert(response);
sendo "response" resposta do ajax

[image: Isto é um alert(response)]

porem na hora que eu tento acessar exemplo response[0].aluno, resultado é undefined.

JS

```js
var hora = $this.find('h1').text();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: "alunos.php",
        data: { 'hora': hora},
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
            // for(var i=0;response.length>i;i++) {
            //    console.log( response[i].nome);
            // }
        }
    });
```

```css
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'vagrant', 'webfit');
    $hora = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hora');
    $sql = "SELECT aluno.nome as aluno from aula, aluno_aula,aluno where aluno.id = aluno_aula.aluno_id AND aluno_aula.aula_id=aula.id AND aula.horaini='{$hora}';"; //monto a query
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql); //executo a query]
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $vetor[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
    }
    echo json_encode($vetor);
?>
```

PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você esta conseguindo utilizar o alert, você esta recebendo uma string, converta a string json para objeto:

```
var dados = JSON.parse(response);
```

Você pode alterar o dataType também, desta forma:

```
var hora = $this.find('h1').text();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "alunos.php",
    data: {'hora': hora},
    success: function(response){

    }
});
```

Exemplo:

```
$(function(){
  var string = '[{"aluno":"Emilie Dickens"},{"aluno":"Dr. Kenny Reilly Sr."}]';

  var dados = JSON.parse(string);
  alert(dados[0].aluno);
  alert(dados[1].aluno);
});
```

Link com o exemplo funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/ws5guo6m/1/

Comment: Se eu fizer quaisquer uma dessas alterações recebo:
[object Object],[object Object]
no lugar que recebia oque representado no alert.
Isso que esta me intrigando estas mudanças deveriam funcionar.

Comment: Mas é isso mesmo, agora você tem que manipular o objeto.

Comment: Vou fazer um exemplo e postar aqui na resposta, só um minuto.

Comment: Atualizei o exemplo

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado essa ideia do JSON.parse(string), resolveu da seguinte forma: var dados = JSON.parse(response);